# Sevidor no reconoce funcion date_create_from_format

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando la función date_create_from_format para las fechas

```
<?php 
$tiempo_pregunta = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $pregunta->fecha." ".$pregunta->hora);
 ?>
```

Pero el problema es que el apache no reconoce esa función de php, ya cheque la configuracion y que la librera para usar esa función esta instalada, también revise que la libreria sea compatible con la versión de php que tiene instalado el servidor y si lo es.

Por que esta pasando esto??

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solucion solamente agregue este código y fue como se soluciono todo

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar esto de dos formas:

Orientado a Objetos:

```
<?php 
$tiempo_pregunta = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y H:i:s','15-Feb-2009 22:10:45');
echo $tiempo_pregunta ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Por procedimientos:

```
<?php
$tiempo_pregunta = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y H:i:s','15-Feb-2009 22:10:45');
echo date_format($tiempo_pregunta , 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```